# prolog program logic wrong

Tags: prolog, logic

I am new to the Prolog programming language. When I give input as fly(x,y), I want a value to be displayed. I was just trying to execute the following code:-

```
fly(x,y):-
   t is 1.5,
   write(t).
```

Can I know what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Variables in Prolog must be uppercase, so change your `x`, `y` and `t` to `X`, `Y` and `T`. Then make sure you throw all that in a file and consult it rather than typing it at the `?- `prompt. Good luck! :)

Comment: Wow!! That worked correctly. Thank you.